# Why does it throw a syntax Error in mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, syntax

This is my html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Node delivered HTML </title>

</head>
<body>
   <div>
    <h1>Send JSON to Node</h1>
        <button onClick="sendJSON()">Send</button>
        <p id ="result"></p>

   </div>
<script>
 var myData = [
    {
        "author": "Bill",
        "title": "Chris",
        "genre": "Chrisdss",
        "price": 20
    },
    {
        "author": "Bill",
        "title": "Chrisss",
        "genre": "Chrdsdss",
        "price": 24
    }
    ]

function sendJSON(){

console.log(myData);
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   // new HttpRequest instance
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
       this.responseText;
    }
 };
xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(myData));

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path')
const app = express()

var TABLE = 'table';
var books =[]
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "0december"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");

});



app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+ '/frontend.html'));
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {

var jsondata = req.body;
var values = [];
console.log(req.body);
for(var i=0; i< jsondata.length; i++){
  values.push([jsondata[i].author,jsondata[i].title,,jsondata[i].genre,,jsondata[i].price]);
}

//Bulk insert using nested array [ [a,b],[c,d] ] will be flattened to (a,b),(c,d)
con.query('INSERT INTO table (author,title,genre,price) VALUES ?', [values], function(err,result) {
  if(err) {
     res.send('Error');
     console.log(err);
  }
 else {
     res.send('Success');
  }
});
});


app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Books API listening on port 3000'))
```

My server runs perfectly but i tried a lot of things and i get an SQL syntax error. I also tried the W3C tutorial but i still got the same error. Maybe its because my db is modified incorrectly?

My model is named table and it contains id,author,title,genre,price id is auto-increment, everything is string except the price which is type of float. Why do i get a syntax error even though my syntax is exactly the same as the tutorials?

EDIT: Error is 
  sqlMessage: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'table (author,title,genre,price) VALUES (\'Bill\', \'Chris\', NULL, \'Chrisdss\', NULL\' at line 1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO table (author,title,genre,price) VALUES (\'Bill\', \'Chris\', NULL, \'Chrisdss\', NULL, 20), (\'Bill\', \'Chrisss\', NULL, \'Chrdsdss\', NULL, 24.1)' }

Comment: Show the error message

Comment: `table` is a poor choice of a name for a table, because it's a reserved word. You should try changing the table's name or wrapping it in backticks in your query, something like this.  ``INSERT INTO `table` (aut...``

Comment: Yeah so i messed up my database is table and my model is Book, so i added 
`database: table`
in my connection and inserted into `books` but now i get
'Column count doesn\'t match value count at row 1',

Answer (score 1):

### Likely solution

For the query `con.query('INSERT ... ?', [values], ...` to work, values should contain arrays of length 4 containing the values of author, title, genre, price.

However, values contains arrays of length 6.

You should remove the nulls from the arrays inside values by replacing

```
values.push([jsondata[i].author,jsondata[i].title,,jsondata[i].genre,,jsondata[i].price]);
```

with

```
values.push([jsondata[i].author,jsondata[i].title,jsondata[i].genre,jsondata[i].price]);
```

Now values contains arrays of length 4 and the bulk insert should work.

### Alternatively solution

If the nulls are intended, you should specify where they are to be inserted.

Change

```
'INSERT INTO table (author,title,genre,price) VALUES ?'
```

to

```
'INSERT INTO table (author,title,null_field_1,genre,null_field_2,price) VALUES ?'
```

where null_field_i is a field you want to populate with a null.

Comment: So a second , removes NULL values?
Now i get this though   code: 'ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW',
  errno: 1136,
  sqlMessage: 'Column count doesn\'t match value count at row 1',
  sqlState: '21S01',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO books (author,title,genre,price) VALUES ((\'Bill\', \'Chris\', \'Chrisdss\', 20), (\'Bill\', \'Chrisss\', \'Chrdsdss\', 24.1))' }

Comment: An extra comma adds <empty slot> into the array, which got intepreted as NULL. As for the error, it seems your query is otherwise correct, but it has en extra set of braces around your values. Try passing values or [[values]] instead of [values].